# Installing Windows 7 on RAID 0 created in Intel Rapid Storage Technology

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ssd, installation, raid

I ordered a ThinkPad T70 from 51nb and upon arrival I fitted 2x Samsung 960 250GB NVMe drives. As per instructions provided to me by 51nb I setup a RAID with the following configuration using Intel Rapid Storage Technology in the BIOS.

```
RAID Level: RAID0(Stripe)
Stripe Size: 128KB
Size: 456.8GB
```

After hours of trying (and numerous Google searches) I'm still unable to get Windows 7 installation to recognise my RAID 0 drive. Due to the laptop being a custom order I can't provide much information, but here's what I have.

```
Intel i7-7820HQ
32GB DDR4-2400
AMT Aptio Setup Utility v2.18.1263
```

Despite loading in Intel's RTI driver (f6flpy.zip, iastorac.inf), still nothing is found. It may also be useful for me to note that in setup the RAID drive does not show up under boot options.

[image: RST Configuration] 
[image: RAID Configuration]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a new machine and Windows 7 is an old operating system.  Windows propbably doesnt recoognize the drive controller.  More than likely you will need to download the proper drivers for the disk controller from Lenovo and manually install them during the Windows 7 install.

Comment: All of the drivers I have found online do not work but as the laptop is custom made I have contacted the manufacturer who said their software engineer will look into the issue.